# Discrepancy between CAD and GIS route lengths

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, autocad

I have imported a route from AutoCAD which is marked every kilometre and converted it into a shapefile. I put markers every 100 m using X-Tools. There is a difference between the two sets of markers, very small at first but growing substantially over the 380 Km route. I'm thinking that the CAD route will also be offset in the same way against the underlying DTM meaning that I can't be sure of the exact distance of any given feature along the route line.

Why is this happening and how do I correct it?

Comment: Hey Will - maybe check the projection information associated with your original CAD drawing, your DTM, and the shapefile to make sure all projection choices between these data sources are consistent? Additionally, check to see if the chosen projection is appropriate for the general study area. It may also be worth a try to collect these layers and [project](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm) each of them to a common projected coordinate system in ArcMap,

Comment: It's possible CAD using 3d length

Comment: I have confirmed the problem as AutoCAD marking geodesic kilometre points and GIS marking linear kilometre points. I'm now trying to find a way to measure and mark the route geodesically in Arcmap.